# Simplification of Boolean Expression in java

Tags: java, boolean-expression, simplification

Is there any tool or library in java which simplifies a boolean expression formula and gives result.

when inputs are like that,

```
exp = (a || a' ) result = 1

exp = ( a || b ) && ( a' || b )  result = b (after simplification)
```

Expressions can be larger or more complex than above.

Comment: By `a'` do you mean "not a"? That should be `!a` in Java. Btw `( a || b ) && ( !a || b )` evaluates to `false`, not `b`. Did you mean `( a && b ) || ( !a && b )` ?

Comment: This is not programming related - to me it looks like you're looking for an application that can simplify *logical* expressions

Comment: Yes Andreas, I'm totaly trying to find a library when I give my expression like,

((a && b) || (c || d' ) && (d' && a)) for example, then library/tool will give a simplified & smaller version of this expression. Of course if expression is applicable to be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ supports ["intentions"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/intentions.jsp) which allow you to simplify boolean expressions within the editor.  Alternatively, [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) can report these kind of errors for you (see the [boolean rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/design.html))

Comment: I like that IntelliJ can check chained if statements like           if (a == null || b == null) {
            
        } else if (a != null && b != null) {
            
        }  It warns the second if condition is always true and offers to remove it for you.

Comment: Thanks to Jeff Foster, but non of these tools are not meeting the expectations to simplify a logical boolean expression. They are source code optimizers, I'm not interested in code, I just want to find a tool / library or a code which can simplify a logical boolean expression.